# Hibernate manytomany cascading

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I got two entities, "project" and "employee", a project cointains 0, 1 or many employees and an employee can participate on 0, 1 or many projects. 
So its a normal many to many relationship and a third table is required...lets call it "ProjectEmployee".

When i delete a project, the project itself should be deleted and the proper entry/entries in ProjectEmployee. But the employees should still exist.
Same for employee...so it should be possible to have many entries in project and in employee but not a single one in ProjectEmployee.

I hope its clear what I would like to have.

The problem is now that I don´t know how the correct mapping(XML) should look like.

At the moment it is as follows:

**Project:**

```
    <set name="employees" table="ProjectEmployee" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="projectId" />
        <many-to-many class="Employee" column="employeeId" />
    </set>
    <set name="modules"  cascade="save-update,delete-orphan" fetch="select" lazy="true" inverse="true">
        <key column="projectId" />
        <one-to-many class="Modul" />
    </set>
</class>
```

**Employee**

```
<class name="Employee">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <generator class="sequence"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="firstName" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="lastName" />
    </property>
    <property name="dateOfBirth" type="date">
        <column name="dateOfBirth" />
    </property>

    <set name="logbookEntries" inverse="true" cascade="save-update,delete-orphan"
        fetch="select" lazy="true">
        <key column="employeeId" />
        <one-to-many class="LogbookEntry" />
    </set>

    <set name="issues" inverse="true" cascade="save-update,delete-orphan"
        fetch="select" lazy="true">
        <key column="employeeId" />
        <one-to-many class="Issue" />
    </set>


    <one-to-one name="address" class="Address" cascade="save-update, delete" />

    <set name="projects" table="ProjectEmployee" inverse="true"
        cascade="save-update">
        <key column="employeeId" />
        <many-to-many class="Project" column="projectId"/>
    </set>
    <joined-subclass name="PermanentEmployee">
        <key column="id" />
        <property name="salary" />
    </joined-subclass>

    <joined-subclass name="TemporaryEmployee">
        <key column="id" />
        <property name="hourlyRate"></property>
        <property name="renter"></property>
        <property name="startDate"></property>
        <property name="endDate"></property>
    </joined-subclass>


</class>
```

At the moment, I get an Exception when I would like to delete an employee.
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Thats because I didnt configure "cascade:delete"!

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you have foriegn key constraint at table level?

Comment: employee and project not ...ProjectEmployee contains two columns (employeeID(FK) and projectID(FK)).